# The scope is enlarged?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to say that the project was going well and so it was decided that the scope would be 'made bigger/enlarged'. Is this correct or how else can I say it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expanded, grew, increased, creeped....

Comment: I believe that the word is "crept".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways this could be said. I do believe the word you're looking for is broaden. i.e. "The project was going very well so we decided to broaden the scope of it to include" (insert areas now being included that were not previously).
I hope this helps!